# How to merge two files based on the matching of two columns? CSV

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, csv, cut

I have file1 likes:

> 6688249-7,03/02/2017,**5515**,02-feb-17
>
> 16914917-8,03/02/2017,**5521**,02-feb-17

And a file2:

> **5515**,6688249-7,06-02-2017 04:25:47 PM,ASIG,ELIZABETH PRIETO
>
> **5515**,6688249-7,06-02-2017 04:56:32 PM,URR,ELIZABETH PRIETO
>
> **5521**,16914917-8,06-02-2017 12:51:04 PM,ASIGN,SOLANGE
>
> **5521**,16914917-8,27-02-2017 04:32:11 PM,Ex,SOLANGE

And would like a file3 such that:

> 6688249-7,03/02/2017,5515,02-feb-17,06-02-2017 04:25:47 PM,ASIG,ELIZABETH PRIETO
>
> 6688249-7,03/02/2017,5515,02-feb-17,06-02-2017 04:56:32 PM,URR,ELIZABETH PRIETO
>
> 16914917-8,03/02/2017,5521,02-feb-17,06-02-2017 12:51:04 PM,ASIGN,SOLANGE
>
> 16914917-8,03/02/2017,5521,02-feb-17,27-02-2017 04:32:11 PM,Ex,SOLANGE

Which means to put the 3th,4th,5th columns of file2 to file1 by the key of the 2nd column (3th column file1, 1th column file 1)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be enough:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$3]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1],$3,$4,$5}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

if output sort order is immaterial, this looks like a job for `join`

```
join -1 3 -2 1 -t, -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.3,2.4,2.5 <(sort -k3,3 -t, file1) \
    <(sort -k1,1 -t, file2)


6688249-7,03/02/2017,5515,02-feb-17,06-02-2017 04:25:47 PM,ASIG,ELIZABETH PRIETO
6688249-7,03/02/2017,5515,02-feb-17,06-02-2017 04:56:32 PM,URR,ELIZABETH PRIETO
16914917-8,03/02/2017,5521,02-feb-17,06-02-2017 12:51:04 PM,ASIGN,SOLANGE
16914917-8,03/02/2017,5521,02-feb-17,27-02-2017 04:32:11 PM,Ex,SOLANGE
```

The inputs to `join` need to be sorted on the join key, the example above uses process substitution( supported by shells such as `bash`) to achieve that